# Form submitted even after onsubmit function returns false

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Html

```
<form action="/users/add" onsubmit="return test();" id="UserForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" maxlength="255" value="" id="UserName" class="form-error"  >
</form
```

Javascript

```
function test() {
    var inputs = $('input:not([inputname])');

    jQuery.each(inputs, function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        $(this).next().removeClass('displayNone');
        return false;
    }
    });

}
```

If I select single input value like below, It works fine for me. It will avoid form being submitted.

```
function test() {
    var value = $('#UserName').val();
    if (value == '') {
    $('#UserName').next().removeClass('displayNone');
    return false;
    }
}
```

How to avoid form submission  when using jQuery.each  function ?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, `test()` does not return false.

There is no return statement in the `test()` function.

The only return statement is in the anonymous function passed to `each`.

Presumably you should be doing something like this:

```
function test() {
    var inputs = $('input:not([inputname])');

    var return_value = true;

    jQuery.each(inputs, function() {
        if (this.value == '') {
            $(this).next().removeClass('displayNone');
            return_value = false;
        }
    });

    return return_Value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `each()` instead of `$.each()` since `inputs` its a jquery collection and not a regular array.
To prevent the form from submitting you can do this instead of inline code:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    if (!test()) {
        e.preventDefault(); // If test fails don't submit
    }
});
```